# Blender 2.8 How do I fix the gloss on this mesh?

Tags: shaders

[image]

I’m using normal maps here, Is it the faulty map or something else that’s causing this strange effect?

How would I turn this into something like this: 
[image]
 Sort of a matte effect

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your scene, your lights, materials, normal maps or render settings. We don't even know what render engine you are using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the point:

- You can change the strength of normal by using **normal map node**
- The second wood of your picture seems to have a **clearcoat** on it, there is an attribute to do that effect too
- The **roughness** change how light reflective

[image]

Try it your self, and most of the time you will get *specular* or *roughness* or *smoothness(?)* image map as well. You can use those images as input